# Figure -table connection with dotted line in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

How could I connect a figure line in tikz with a table next to it like the following picture?
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs} 
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\geometry{left=0.75in,right=0.75in,top=0.65in,bottom=0.65in}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
    \usepackage{tkz-fct} \usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{$P$} & \textbf{$Q_A$} \\ 
\hline
10 & 5\\ 
\hline
8 & 8  \\ 
\hline
6 & 12 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xlabel=$Q$ ,
  ylabel=$P$ ]
\addplot table [y=P, x=$Q_A$]{data_1.txt};
\addlegendentry{$Q_A$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

This does require a bit of manual adjustments, so for longer tables it would be quite tedious. For this case it's not too bad though.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable,booktabs}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\pgfplotstableread{%
Q P
5 10
8 8
12 6
}\mydata
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  name=myaxis,
  xmin=4.5,xmax=12.5,
  ymin=5.5,ymax=10.5,
  axis y line=left,
  axis x line=bottom,
  xlabel=$Q$ ,
  ylabel=$P$ ]
\addplot table \mydata;
\addlegendentry{$Q_A$}

\coordinate (c1) at (axis cs:5,10);
\coordinate (c2) at (axis cs:8,8);
\coordinate (c3) at (axis cs:12,6);
\end{axis}
\node (tablenode) [right=2cm of myaxis] {\pgfplotstabletypeset[every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}]\mydata};

\foreach \C/\Y in {c1/0.4, c2/0.6, c3/0.8}
 \draw [thick,dashed] (\C) -- ($(tablenode.north west)!\Y!(tablenode.south west)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```